# Reading data from columns in Excel

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

I am working on a python script to read data from columns in an Excel file and using that data to execute commands on a Cisco switch.

For example, I have below 2 columns

```
Switch        MAC
aaa.com      mac.aaa.000
bbb.com      mac.bbb.000
ccc.com      mac.ccc.000
.....        .....
```

The python will now go to switch aaa and will set port security with mac mac.aaa.000 as sticky.

This is the command:

```
switchport port-security **<mac-address>** sticky
```

Now I have login part done and I can execute commands. I need help with the part which reads 2 columns from file and know to login to switch a and sticky macaaa on corresponding column.

Here is how I am logging in and executing commands on switch:

```
term_len = "term len 0"
# Need a loop here that gets switchname from coulmn A and assign it to variable host and also corresponding MAC address and assigns it to variable MAC
host = ""
MAC = ""
session = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
session.write(cred.username + '\n')
session.read_until('Password: ')
session.write(cred.password + '\n')
session.read_until('>')
session.write(cred.en + '\n')
session.read_until('Password: ')
session.write(cred.en_pass + '\n')
session.read_until('#')
session.write(term_len + '\n')
session.write(switchport port-security **MAC** sticky + '\n')
```

Please help. The loop will read all switches and MAC from files and executes the sticky command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using openpyxl to read excel data into scripts.

```
    from openpyxl import *
    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename,askdirectory,asksaveasfilename
    #file selector using tkinter
    file = askopenfilename()
    #load the workbook
    wb=load_workbook(file)
    #get sheets
    sheets = wb.sheetnames
    #select sheet to use by index from sheetnames
    ws=wb[sheets[0]]
    #loop through the rows of worksheet and store in list
    switchMAC=[]
    for r in range (ws.max_row):
        row=[]
        for c in range(ws.max_column):
            row.append(ws.cell(row=r+1,column=c+1).value)
        switchMAC.append(row)
```

From here you now have a list of lists (switchMAC) you can loop through to pass your commands

```
    for r in switchMac:
        host=r[0]
        MAC=r[1]
        #add the rest of your code for each host within the loop
```

Comment: I downloaded openpyxl folder but can't seem to find tkinter. I did Tkinter and it recognized it but "skopenfilename" etc has red lines.  My co-worker told me that reading data from excel is not advised so will you please be able to add solution for a simple txt file.  It will have switch and couple spaces and then MAC address, then next line and so on.

Comment: You're best bet at that point is to format as csv in your text(Host,Mac) editor and use the standard csv library and the same for loop process as described above. https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: @Damon tkinter isn't a part of the openpyxl library, it is a different python package.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xlrd](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd), This script allows you to transform an excel data table to a list of dictionaries:

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('foo.xls')
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('foo.xls', on_demand = True)
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
first_row = [] # The row where we stock the name of the column
for col in range(worksheet.ncols):
    first_row.append( worksheet.cell_value(0,col) )
# transform the workbook to a list of dictionaries
data =[]
for row in range(1, worksheet.nrows):
    elm = {}
    for col in range(worksheet.ncols):
        elm[first_row[col]]=worksheet.cell_value(row,col)
    data.append(elm)
print data
```

You can also use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html)

```
from pandas import *
xls = ExcelFile('foo.xls')
df = xls.parse(xls.sheet_names[0])
print df.to_dict()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to read data from the excel files.

```
import os
import datetime
import sys
import re
import openpyxl
import uuid
from openpyxl import load_workbook

class ExcelDictSmall(dict):
    '''
    Dictionary with all Sheet Names as key, value is a List of Rows each item in a Row List is a List of Cells
    '''
    def __init__(self,dir,fname):
        fullFname = os.path.join(dir,fname)
        wb = load_workbook(filename=fullFname, read_only=True)
        allSheets= wb.get_sheet_names()
        for sheet in allSheets:
            sheetList = []
            rowlist=[]
            for row in wb[sheet].rows:
                for cell in row:
                    rowlist.append(cell.value)
                sheetList.append(rowlist)
                rowlist=[]
            self[sheet]=sheetList
```